# Is it good practice to use an iframe to login with OAuth2 and OpenID

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

I am looking into using OAuth2 and OpenID for single-sign-on.  But I'm concerned about redirecting users to login from the various existing websites I would like to start using this with because of styling differences.  Is it good practice to display the identity server login page in an iframe to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use redirection if you are using end user consent based login from Google, facebook or other web based providers but if your usecase belongs to enterprise scenario (I mean inside the firewal saftey of big companies) then you can go for password grant based flow where-in your application collects the details of end user and submits them directly to OAuth server (but this flow doesn't involve user consent, so decide what you want).

Comment: I know I could use the Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow, but some of the websites are available externally, so I'm not wanting to expose user names and passwords by using that.  We are planning on developing our own identity server.

Comment: For websites which are external, you should follow federation scenario where in using redirection based flow wherein you should instead of iframe open a new window which uses Implicit flow (for javascript client running inside the browser) and authz code based flow for server side applications. Now for styling, since it is your own identity server then I guess styling should not be issue.

Comment: It's just that the websites I will be using this with use a variety of styling.  I'm just looking for a way to have the styling blend in without having to direct them to a login page with different styling or have to style it based on the source site.